# How can I prevent my Azure Function from stopping message consuming from Kafka topic?

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, azure-functions

I have create an azure function to consume messages from Kafka topic. The solution is deployed in azure. The function stops consuming messages after a while and needs restart.

This is my code:

```
public class Consumers
{
    private readonly string connectionString = "db connection";

    [FunctionName(nameof(Consumer1))]
    public async Task Consumer1(
        [KafkaTrigger("BrokerList",
            "kafka-default-topic",
            Username = "kafka",
            Password = "%KafkaPassword%",
            Protocol = BrokerProtocol.SaslSsl,
            AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.ScramSha512,
            ConsumerGroup = "foo")] KafkaEventData<string>[] events,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            foreach (KafkaEventData<string> eventData in events)
            {
                await ProccessMessage(eventData.Value, connection);
            }
        }
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(Consumer2))]
    public async Task Consumer2(
    [KafkaTrigger("BrokerList1",
                "kafka-default-topic",
                Username = "kafka",
                Password = "%KafkaPassword%",
                Protocol = BrokerProtocol.SaslSsl,
                AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.ScramSha512,
                ConsumerGroup = "foo")] KafkaEventData<string>[] events,
    ILogger log)
    {

        await using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            foreach (KafkaEventData<string> eventData in events)
            {
                await ProccessMessage(eventData.Value, connection);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProccessMessage(string msgString, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        var logEntry = new Log
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            error = string.Empty,
            input = msgString,
            updated_at = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
        try
        {
            var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(msgString);
            var entity = GetEntity(input.Metadata.TableName, msgString);
            var operation = input.Metadata.Operation;
            await entity.Save(connection, operation);
            await logEntry.Save(connection);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logEntry.error = e.ToString();
            await logEntry.Save(connection);
        }

    }

    private IEntity GetEntity(string tableName, string json)
    {
        switch (tableName)
        {
            case "gateway_transactions":
                var transactions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionData>(json);
                return transactions.Data;
            case "gateway_companies":
                var companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompaniesData>(json);
                return companies.Data;
            case "gateway_merchants_sites":
                var merchants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MerchantsData>(json);
                return merchants.Data;
            case "gateway_providers":
                var providers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProvidersData>(json);
                return providers.Data;
            case "crypto_admins_users":
                var caud = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoAdminUsersData>(json);
                return caud.Data;
            case "gateway_providers_to_merchants":
                var ptmd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProvidersToMerchantsData>(json);
                return ptmd.Data;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"DataFactory cannot build object for table: {tableName} with payload: {json}");
        }
    }

}
```

I read that an unhandled exception may cause this issue, but I think I have wrapped the code so that to catch the possible exception.

Comment: Are you using the Consumption or Premium plan?

Comment: I am using Pay-As-You-Go